# generate right click and select custom menu R shiny JS automatically

Tags: javascript, r, shinyjs

I have created the following App using R Shiny

```
  library(shiny)
  library(rhandsontable)
  library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(  
sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel = "Inputparameter",
            numericInput(inputId = "Noi", label = "Row Count", value = 7, 0, max = 1000)),mainPanel (useShinyjs(),rHandsontableOutput(outputId = 'Adjusttable', width ='100%', height 
= '100%'),dataTableOutput(outputId = "Init_Tbl")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {    
DF <-reactive({
DF_Out<-data.frame(ID = 1:5,'Column2' = 0, Start = "D",FM="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
return(DF_Out)})

output$Adjusttable<-renderRHandsontable({  
input_Val<-input$Noi  
js_func<-paste("function (key, options) {this.alter('insert_row',[0],", 
input_Val,");this.render();}")
 ###
namestate<-paste("Add",input_Val, "rows at the bottom") 
output_Adjusttable<- DF() %>% head(5) %>% rhandsontable(width = 280, height = 677,stretchH = 
"all") %>%hot_context_menu(customOpts = list(insert_row = list(name = namestate,callback = 
htmlwidgets::JS(js_func))))
return(output_Adjusttable)}, quoted = FALSE )} 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the js_func line generates a right click option that adds extra rows. The number of extra rows is determined by the numericinput row count. Is it possible to automatically add the extra rows by the numericinput without the right click.

Answer (score 1):

This example, will add as many empty rows to the output as given by `input$Noi`. The idea is that you create an empty `data.frame` which has `input$Noi` rows and `rbind` it to your original `data.frame`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(  
   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel = "Inputparameter",
                 numericInput("Noi", "Row Count", 7, 0, 1000)),
   mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("Adjusttable", "100%", "100%"),
             dataTableOutput("Init_Tbl"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {    
   DF <- reactive({
      DF_Out <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                           Column2 = 0, 
                           Start = "D",
                           FM = "")
      df_fill <- data.frame(ID = NA_integer_,
                            Column2 = NA_real_,
                            Start = NA_character_,
                            FM = NA_character_)[rep(1L, input$Noi), ]
      res <- rbind(DF_Out,
                   df_fill)
      rownames(res) <- NULL
      res
   })
   
   output$Adjusttable <- renderRHandsontable({  
      DF() %>% 
         rhandsontable(width = 280, 
                       height = 677,
                       stretchH = "all")
   })
} 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In this case, if we add extra rows, the  table resets to zero. If we fill values, and then increase the number of rows, new rows need to be added without resetting the table sir.

Comment: Your requirements are then at all not clear. Whatt happens if I select `7` then change some values in the table, and then select `6`. Work on your requirements then I cna help you further. Most likely your problem can be solved with `hot_to_r`.